# How to handle Inputs having type as "file"?

Tags: html, input

I am using a  element in my page which consists a bunch of input fields like first_name, last_name, profile_pic etc and based on user input, I save this data in backend by using a POST call. I am getting all this form data using following line:

```
fd = new FormData(mentorForm[0]);
```

and then I am simply sending this form data using following code:

```
$.ajax({
              url: "my url",
              type: "PUT",
              data: fd,
          })
```

I am able to update profile pic and all other fields without any problem.
But I am facing a problem that every time I update any value in form (and not input file type field), it sends null for input type file as I have not selected anything in it. Can someone help me understand how to prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

Every default AJAX call will process your data. So to prevent that add the following two attributes to the request:

```
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```

So your AJAX call looks then like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "my url",
    type: "PUT",
    data: fd,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
});
```

Comment: Yep, added but how does that help me to prevent my problem. Whenever lets say I update the first_name, the payload which goes with the request is taking "input=file"'s value as null as I am not updating it and updating it in backend as null deleting my previous picture. How to prevent that?